# Elastic search Match query with comma value not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Hi We wanted to suppot both partial search and exact match for one filed category.

Here is the mapping for category , We achieved this with **fields.raw**

```
"category": {
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                            "search_analyzer": "standard",
                            "fields": {
                                "raw": {
                                   "type": "string",
                                   "index": "not_analyzed"
                                }
                             }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Everything is working as expected , I am able to do both exact and partial search.
But When I am having char comma "," in the data , Exact match is not working.
**I am searching with category.name.raw,  which is not_analyzed filed**

```
 { "query": {
"filtered": {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "",
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "fields": [
              "filed1",
              "field2^12"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "category.name.raw": " Poverty, Poor and Hunger"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}}}
```

I am not getting any results, I am not sure what I am doing wrong, Please help me to fix this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: which version of ES you are using, `string` is deprecated in latest versions.a

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja We are using older version 2.X , Keyword data type is not supporting in this version

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja 2.4.4 is the version

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below analyzer:

```
        "lower_whitespace" : {
          "filter" : [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "type" : "custom",
          "tokenizer" : "whitespace"
        }
```

for more details check below about tokenizers:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html

And it seems you using an old version from Elastic search consider upgrading will be a great idea

Comment: I am searching with category.name.raw, which is not_analyzed filed

Comment: Since your trying to fin part of the text use analyzer will make your search more efficient, so I think it's better to use analyzer and using whitespace one will make you be able to search for comma ","

Comment: Yes, it works. I have es 7.4 and it's working with me ;)

Comment: @ahmadadawi If i add white space analyzer then I will not be able to do exact match , There are many categories that consists common words

Comment: To do an exact match or to do aggregations try to create another field with the type keyword and you can use copy_to feature to do.
To have more details check below:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

Comment: We are not able to update elastic search version, keyword type is not supported in this version

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: @ahmadadawi he mentioned 2.4.4 earlier in my comment

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
    {
      "match": {
        "category.name.raw": " Poverty, Poor and Hunger"
      }
    }
```

Whilst the targeted field is mapped as `not_analyzed` (aka `keyword` in newer versions of Elasticsearch), the query input here will be analyzed. I *think* it'll inherit the `standard` analyzer defined for the `search_analyzer` on `category.name`.

If you need an **exact match**, use a `term` query instead of the `match` query.